# Image camera quality is bad

Tags: android, image, android-camera-intent

My code :

```
final Uri fileUri = null;
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, 2);

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Uri final = getImageUri((Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data"));
        final String filePath = getPath(final);
    }
}
```

Get image uri :

```
public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap inImage) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), inImage, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}
```

After this, my image is bad quality

How i can fix it ?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of passing `null` for `EXTRA_OUTPUT`, [use it to get a full-size image](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#TaskPath), rather than a thumbnail.

Comment: @CommonsWare Can you help me more ?

Comment: I linked to documentation in my previous comment. [Here is a sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.13/Camera/FileProvider) (covered in [this book](https://commonsware.com/Android)) that implements it, though it uses `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` rather than `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE_SECURE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because of compression. If you really need to compress it try to use:

```
Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, width, height, true);
```

please also have a look here, maybe you can find something that will work better for you:

https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java

Comment: Thank you, where i use it ?

Comment: try to modify your method like:
`public Uri getImageUri(Bitmap inImage) {
    Bitmap bitmapScaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(inImage, width, height, true);
    String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(), bitmapScaled, "Title", null);
    return Uri.parse(path);
}`

Comment: not work for me